# systemd service starts ok, but hangs after restart

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, .net, ubuntu-20.04

I am having a weird problem, I have set up a custom systemd service running a dotnet project. When the system first starts up, the service also starts just fine, however when I restart it, it hangs.

System is Ubuntu 20.04 on Azure.

Here's the service description:

```
[Unit]
Description=Api

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/aviad/Backend
ExecStart=/snap/bin/dotnet run -c AzureDev --launch-profile AzureDev
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
User=aviad

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the result of `sudo systemctl status api`

```
● api.service - Api
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/api.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-09-14 15:51:50 UTC; 29min ago
   Main PID: 855 (dotnet)
      Tasks: 39 (limit: 9513)
     Memory: 314.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/api.service
             ├─ 855 /snap/dotnet-sdk/120/dotnet run -c AzureDev --launch-profile AzureDev
             └─2408 /home/aviad/Backend/bin/AzureDev/net5.0/Backend
```

And this is the status after a restart:

```
● api.service - Api
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/api.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-09-14 16:33:33 UTC; 7s ago
   Main PID: 8373 (dotnet)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 9513)
     Memory: 460.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/api.service
             ‣ 8373 /snap/dotnet-sdk/120/dotnet run -c AzureDev --launch-profile AzureDev

Sep 14 16:33:33 machine1 systemd[1]: Started Api.
```

Apart from the bad status, the actual project doesn't really run.

Some more things I tried and had the same (bad) result:

1. Stop the service, wait a while, then start it
2. Disable the service, wait a while, then enable it
3. Do the above after and before a `systemctl daemon-reload`
4. Issued a `kill -9` to the process id and let `systemd` restart it

Comment: Is there something unusual about your home directory?

Comment: Nothing that I have done knowingly

Comment: It appears that installing dotnet using snap is the problem. I removed it using snap and then installed it using apt and it now works...